# Azure Query.where() with or

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

How I can do somthing like that:

```
var userId="patrick";
var finded="bob";
query.where({
    userhostid: userId || finded,
});
```

I just need to add to query items where userhostid quals to userId or finded
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function way of specifying the condition:

```
var userId="patrick";
var finded="bob";
query.where(function(value1, value2) {
    return this.userhostid == value1 || this.userhostid == value2;
}, userId, finded);
```

The blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/09/21/playing-with-the-query-object-in-read-operations-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx has more information on complex filtering in queries.

Comment: Man You are my master! Litres of beer for you!!